# How to create global variable in karate?

Tags: web-services, automated-tests, karate

I have configured base URL, and now I have to configure one variable(storied), which will be used in the many of the requests. for running test 2-3 times for different stores I need to manually go to every feature and modify storied.
So how would I declare a global variable and how to bind it to a request?

Answer (score 3):

The same way like you did `baseUrl`, just add a variable in `karate-config.js` and it will be available in all tests.

If you set a variable using `def` it will be available to the rest of the scenario. If you want re-use, use a `Background` section or look at the documentation for `call`.

(edit:)

Refer to the documentation please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration

If this is confusing, just spend 5 minutes with anyone who knows JavaScript and make them read the above section. You will get a solution in no time. All the best !

Comment: this might not be ideal given the scenario: I need feature to create account, another feature to create "container", and few other to add service to that container, I will need the ID of the "container" lets say, it would be preferable to be able to store the ID as a global value after a call rather than calling it for each "add service" feature file. Its being able to store global values vs having one huge feature file vs having to call a script for fetching ID for each feature script that needs it.

Comment: @DusanGligoric this is what `callSingle()` is for, but I don't recommend it the way you want to - as it is a very bad pattern and couples multiple features together. here you go: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks